# Парсинг строки RxJava с изменением типа

Tags: java, android, парсер, rxjava

Из очереди берем строку, парсим ее и проверяем соотвествует ли она требованиям. Если соответствует, то отдаем в обработку соответствующему методу, но **отдать нужно уже не строку, а массив строк, который был получен в результате парсинга .split**

**Берем из очереди и парсим..** ((filterLog) подчеркнуто красным)

```
Observable<String> logObservable =
        Observable.from(sQueueOfUnprocessedLogs).filter(filterLog);
```

**filter**

```
 Func1<String, String[]> filterLog = new Func1<String, String[]>() {

    @Override
    public String[] call(String str) {
        String[] parsedLog = str.split("\\|");
            if (mDebugType.contains(parsedLog[VALIDATION])) {
                return parsedLog;
            }
        return null;
    }
};
```

**Observer**

```
 Observer<String[]> observer = new Observer<String[]>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(String[] parsedLog) {
        formingPOJO(parsedLog);
    }
};
```

**Нужно получить массив, а не строку**

Answer (score 0):

добавь в конце `.toList()` что бы получилось

```
Observable<String> logObservable = Observable.from(sQueueOfUnprocessedLogs)
    .filter(filterLog)
    .toList();
```

тогда результатом будет массив строк